# Filter to copy specific sets of data using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, replication, database-replication

I am starting to learn about Azure Data Factory. I was wondering if I can create a pipeline to copy only specific records from the origin data source to the destination.

Imagine it is only on-premise SQL database to Azure SQL Database, but instead of copying all the rows in a given dataset, I would like to pass a parameter to the pipeline and use it in a sort of where clause to decide which records I want to copy to the destination.

Is that something I can do with ADF, parameters and triggers or do I need something else?

Thank you in advance for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use `Copy Data` tool to specify the query for the source. Generally ADF is powerful enough to let you manipulate data in many ways.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-hello-world-copy-data-tool